# Bad Alloc with Global Vector

Tags: c++, vector

I want to pass in a instruction "iinc(10, 20)" and I want to add too a global vector each number in the instruction. So my global vector should be <10><20> afterwards. I am getting a run time error that says

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_aloc' 
what(): std:: bad_aloc
aborted
```

Code:

```
vector<int> number_list;

void add_number(string input)
{
int count = 5;
vector<char> trythis;
 while(input[count] != ')')
 {
    do{ 
      trythis.push_back(input[count];
      count++;
    }while(input[count] != ',');
    string temp(trythis.begin(), trythis.end());
    int real = atoi(temp.cstr());
    number_list.push_back(real);
    count++;
  }

}
```

Comment: When posting error messages (as well as code), please *copy and paste* it instead of rewriting it and adding possible errors and mistakes. Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What is `string temp(temp.begin(), temp.end());` supposed to achieve?

Comment: stringtemp(temp.begin(), temp.end()) is supposed to take a char vector of <1><0><2> and make a string called temp =102

Comment: And continuing with the above questioning, what is `temp.cstr()`?

Comment: `std::bad_alloc` is thrown by `std::allocator` whenever it fails to allocate memory, usually indicating out-of-memory scenario. Sounds like you're allocating/resizing something based on uninitialized values.

Comment: `trythis.push_back(input[count]<need ) here>;`

Comment: This code fails to compile, where's `if` that matches your `else`?

Comment: While it's possible to guess what and where the problem is, we should not have to do it. That's why it's so important with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And if the question is not about build errors, then make sure the code you show us actually *builds!* That's why I http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/. As well as http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/.

Comment: @mhemmy you should then build `temp` based on `trythis` I assume.

Comment: The else was a leftover from some other code, I removed it.

Answer (score 3):

```
string temp(temp.begin(), temp.end());
```

Variable 'temp' is uninitialized when used within its own initialization

Comment: That's legal. Not Spock approved, but legal.

Comment: which is then converted to an int with atoi ?

Comment: @user4581301 It *builds* but it leads to *undefined behavior* so the legality of it could be debated.

Comment: Point taken. Syntactically legal. Logically fubar.